# Aggregating Kafka records in python

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregate

I want streams of records from kafka to be aggregated. I know there is kafka stream implementation in JAVA but I am not familiar with JAVA and want to know are there any options to perform such task in python and how good is it compared to kafka streams?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Faust? It's the Python equivalent of Kafka Streams

Alternatively, there's nothing preventing you from dumping consumer records into a collection